# Suppress page number from ToC item (using 'addtocontents')

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, books

This would seem to be straightforward, but I can't seem to figure out how to suppress page numbers showing in the ToC for items added using `\addcontentsline`.

I would like the ToC to show a line of text "Poetry Era" without the page reference then immediately below a poem title with the page number.

I don't want to use `\chapter` or `\section` as I want my content to only be poems (which is represented by the `section` headings in the MWE.

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Poetry Era}
    \section{First Section}
    \lipsum[1-12]
    \section{Second Section}
    \lipsum[13-27]
    \section{Third Section}
    \lipsum{28-44]}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Poetry Era}
    \section{Fourth Section}
    \lipsum[45-58]
    \section{Fifth Section}
    \lipsum[59-65]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Poetry Era}
    \section{Sixth Section}
    \lipsum[66-72]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe try something like this: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent\bfseries Poetry Era}`.

Comment: \addcontentsline will always pass the page number, but you can modify `\l@chapter` to not display it.  Do you still want the `\@pnumwidth` gap on the right?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I believe I do as I believe `\@\pnumwidth` is used by other contents items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it was defined a new command `addcontentslinex` that will generate the entry to the `toc` without the page number.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\addcontentslinex#1#2#3{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}{}\protected@file@percent}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{chapter}{Poetry Era 1}
    \section{First Section}
    \lipsum[1-12]
    \section{Second Section}
    \lipsum[13-27]
    \section{Third Section}
    \lipsum{28-44]}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{chapter}{Poetry Era 2}
    \section{Fourth Section}
    \lipsum[45-58]
    \section{Fifth Section}
    \lipsum[59-65]
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{chapter}{Poetry Era 3}
    \section{Sixth Section}
    \lipsum[66-72]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @simon-dispa. That works. I've decided to use the `tocloft` package as there are several other changes I need for my ToC to look the way I want.